# How to write a package test in R to see if warning is correctly thrown?

Tags: r, unit-testing, package, warnings

I'm writing some tests for an R package and would like to have `R CMD check` verify that functions display the correct warnings for certain inputs.  But I can't figure out how to capture the warning output so that I can test it.

So if I have a function like:

```
throwsWarning<-function(x){
  if(x>0){
    warning('Argument "x" is greater than zero, results may be incorrect')
  }
  # do something useful ...
}
```

I'd want a something in my test file like:

```
warningOutput <-try( throwsWarning(1))
if (warningOutput!='Argument "x" is greater than zero, results may be incorrect'){
  stop('function "throwsWarning" did not produce correct warning when x>0')
}
```

So far I've found possible partial solutions by changing `options` so that warnings are treated as errors and the surrounding with a `trycatch` block.  Also considered testing value of `last.warning`, but that seems dangerous if the warning is not thrown (would test previous value).  Seems like there must be an easy way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: You don't seem to be using `testthat` in your tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [testthat package](https://github.com/hadley/test_that) has an [`expect_warning`](https://github.com/hadley/test_that/blob/master/R/expectations.r#L402) and [`gives_warning`](https://github.com/hadley/test_that/blob/master/R/expectations.r#L385) function that you can use.

From the examples, you would do something like this:

```
R> library(testthat)
R> expect_that(warning("this is a warning"), gives_warning("is a"))
## This does not raise an error, but:
R> expect_that(warning("this is a warning"), gives_warning("nope"))
Error: warning("this is a warning") does not match 'nope'. Actual value: 
this is a warning
```

So, `gives_warning` is regular expression that is matched against the warning that is supposed to be emitted. If the regex does not match (or no warning is thrown), then a red flag is raised.

Equally, using the shorter `expect_warning`:

```
R> expect_warning(warning("this is a warning"), "is a")
```

Comment: Lovely! I can't believe I've been writing tests all this time without testthat. Would be great if CRAN suggested it in the package writing docs. Seems like the only downside is adding an extra dependency just to run the tests.

Comment: Glad to have tuned you in to a package that wasn't on your radar -- especially since the package in question is totally awesome ;-) Also, put `testthat` in the `Suggests` field -- it doesn't need to be in `Depends` or `Imports`, so you would only be adding a dependency to the package for those people that actually want to run the tests (not just people who want to use your package).

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing your own package, it might make sense to make use of R's condition system by throwing (and catching) particular types of errors or warnings. So

```
myFun <- function(x) {
    if (any(is.na(x))) {
        w <- simpleWarning("'x' contains NA values")
        class(w) <- c("HasNA", class(w))
        warning(w)
    }
    if (any(x < 0))
        warning("'x' contains values less than 0")
    x
}
```

and then in your test, e.g., with `library(RUnit)`, use `tryCatch` and pick off just the conditions that you're interested in testing, i.e., warnings with class `HasNA`:

```
test_myFun_NAwarning <- function() {
    warnOccurred <- FALSE
    tryCatch(myFun(1:5), HasNA = function(w) warnOcccurred <<- TRUE)
    checkTrue(!warnOccurred)
    tryCatch(myFun(-(1:5)), HasNA = function(w) warnOcccurred <<- TRUE)
    checkTrue(!warnOccurred)
    tryCatch(myFun(c(1:5, NA)), HasNA = function(w) warnOccurred <<- TRUE)
    checkTrue(warnOccurred)
}
```

leading to

```
> test_myFun_NAwarning()
[1] TRUE
Warning message:
In myFun(-(1:5)) : 'x' contains values less than 0
```

which shows that tryCatch is catching just the particular warning you're interested in, and doing so in a way that does not rely on matching the text of the string. Maybe you'd have a helper function `.warn` to make all warnings for your package. See `?withCallingHandlers` for additional detail; `withCallingHandlers` and `muffleRestart` are how one might cope with continuing evaluation after a warning occurred, rather than stopping the way `tryCatch` does.